# Adding bullet points to text boxes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, list

I need to be able to add bullet points to a text box so I can display a list on my map.  The work-around that I tried was to format the font differently and use a Wingdings character that looks like a bullet point.  This will work in the meantime, but instead of a top-to-bottom centered dot, the dot was situated more to the top.  It will work if need be, but I thought maybe someone else might have encountered the same problem.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Using 10.0 desktop

Comment: try <li>text</li> for formatting it is unlisted here http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Formatting_tags_available_in_ArcMap/00s800000017000000/

Comment: @Mapperz Have you ever been able to get the li tag to actually work in a layout text element?  If so, did you have to enclose it in other formatting tags or what?  I've tried an been unable to get any standard HTML list tags to work in ArcGIS Desktop layout text elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing up the text in MS Word or word processing program of your choice, copy said text, then add a new text box to the layout and past the text you typed up into that text box.  You may have to go back and do a bit of re-formatting (tweak it to have the desired layout) such as replacing the tab character with desired number of spaces and add a couple of spaces to the left of the bullet to get it indented as compared to non-bulleted portions, etc....  But it should at lest give you the basics of the list for you to work with as you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I used Word to make the list with bullet points and it copy/pasted right into a text box.  There is some tweaking with spacing, but very easy to do.  Ironically enough, the bullet points (and text) are Arial font (my default).  I should be able to pull that symbol somehow without having to copy/paste.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it solved your problem, you may want to mark my answer as accepted or post your own answer explaining how you solved it and mark that answer as accepted. Either way, if you mark an answer as accepted it will remove it from the unanswered questions list, so it's easier to find questions where people still need help. To accept an answer just go to the left side of a question under the vote up/down arrows and there should be a check mark to click that'll turn green when you accept an answer.  And agreed, bullet should be available, but may have to access it via unicode??

Comment: There's always the good old Character Map. Haven't tried it in ArcGIS specifically, but that's what I've used in similar situations in the past. http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/charmap.html

Comment: I always forget about the character map!  I tried that too, and it worked.  Just took some time to find a good symbol.  Thanks!

Comment: I have had trouble using bullets from MS Word. Looked great in ArcMap but when I exported to PDF the font was all messed up.